# I have a variable but it's not being read as anything

Tags: php, sql

I have the variable `$sqlSafety` which looks like this:

```
$sqlSafety = "
        SELECT DISTINCT Assault/142.1333 *100 AS 'Safety'
        FROM crimenumbers 
        WHERE District = 'Area' AND `Month Year` = 'JAN20'";
```

The outcome of this code is then supposed to be checked by this function

```
    if ( $sqlSafety > 131 ) {
      print( "This area is not safe" );
    } else if ( $sqlSafety < 69 ) {
      print( "This area is safe");
    } else {
      print( "This area is neutral");
    }
```

But no matter what `$sqlSafety` equals it only ever responds with the if else statements outcome "This area is safe "

I know that `$sqlSafety` outputs a number as I've been using another line to display what number is comes up with:

```
if ( $result->num_rows > 0 ) {
          while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
            print( "Safety: " . $row[ 'Safety' ] . "<br>" );
```

I'm assuming that problem is that the variable is being read as words when I reference it in the IF statements instead of numbers which I'm assuming would be the equivalent of 0 to the code but I have no idea how to make it read as numbers. If that is even the problem.

Comment: what is the output of `var_dump($sqlSafety);`

Comment: also you shouldn't be having quotes around Safety in the query, use backticks instead

Comment: Akintunde-Rotimi The results of var_dump($sqlSafety); is: string(139) " SELECT DISTINCT Assault/142.1333 *100 AS 'Safety' FROM crimenumbers WHERE District = 'Far North' AND `Month Year` = 'JAN20'"

Answer (score 0):

Your `$sqlSafety` is not a variable it is SQL query, what gives you result is code after that when you execute that query, you can not use `$sqlSafety` for anything but executing a query, on server and after that fetch the results, you need to use $result and $row as you said it your self, that gives a results

```
    if ( $result->num_rows > 0 ) {
              while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
                    if ( $row[ 'Safety' ] > 131 ) {
                          print( "This area is not safe" );
                        } else if ( $row[ 'Safety' ] < 69 ) {
                          print( "This area is safe");
                        } else {
                          print( "This area is neutral");
                        }
};
};
```

try this.